# Does javascript singleton require double parentheses?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

- I created a Singleton-like function for a Google Sheet of mine;
- `Priv` and `Pub` is my way of simulating Private and Public;
- When I assign its instance to a variable, I need to type `()()` so it works the way I want it to. I want to be able to type `Priv.whateverProp`
- I've tried double parentheses in other places inside the Singleton function, but when I accomplish getting to use only one `()`, then the completions display `apply, bind, call etc`.
- Then I have to `getInstance()()`*`.completions**`* again to access the instance properties, but when I run the program, it says *`SingletonFinder().getInstance() is not a function`*
- So I have to leave *getInstance()* with its single parentheses and type `Priv().whaterverProp` instead of `Priv.whateverProp` for the rest of the code, which I don't want.
- Why do I have to type it this way `let Priv = SingletonFinder().getInstance()()` ?

```
function GetFinder(){
    let Pub = {}
    let Priv = SingletonFinder().getInstance()()
    // the rest of the code...
}

function SingletonFinder() {
    let Priv = {}
    let Pub = {}

    /** @type {Class_Finder} */
    Priv.instance = null;
    Priv.createInstance = function () {
        return Class_Finder
    }
    Pub.getInstance = function () {
        if(!Priv.instance) {
            Priv.instance = Priv.createInstance()
        }
        return Priv.instance
    };
    return Pub
}

function Class_Finder() {
    // properties
}
```

Comment: This is the culprit `return Class_Finder`. You're returning a function not the result of that function. Try `return Class_Finder()`.

Comment: Not directly related but your singleton is not a singleton. Every time you call `SingletonFinder().getInstance()` you get a new instance created. Look into the Module pattern using an IIFE if you want something that acts more like a singleton.

Comment: I don't know in what environment you're using this but the latest version of JavaScript has classes and even private class properties.

Comment: @Titus when I do that, the completions go " apply, bind, call etc." u know

Comment: That's a lot of code just to create _an object_ ... `const singleton = { ... };` ...

Comment: @JonasWilms depite the names, I'm creating Classes actually

Comment: @Titus every coder I meet tells me not to uses JS Classes and inheritance, especially for small uses, like my case :|

Comment: @VLAZ thank you so much. I've found [this](https://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and [this link](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/singleton/) and corrected my Singleton.